# In Google Sheets, is there a way to Insert an Image into a Cell by creating a button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to use a specifically formatted spreadsheet for work that requires photos to be center aligned into cells that must not change in size. One photo per cell. This document is extensive and can easily require me to insert up to 40+ personal camera photos from my Desktop every time I use this sheet. I would like to know if I can have a button or some solution that shortens the repetition of having to navigate to the submenu option “Insert image in cell” for every photo?

I have tried to use workarounds involving Google Forms and the Image() function, but my photos are private and cannot be shared. I have learned that the image function only works on publicly accessible files. I have very little experience with Macros and Apps Script so I have not tried that route yet. I am trying to get the Upload image into cell menu with a single click in a cell (like a button) or a short keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Hy PhxWizard0231

It is a bit hard to clearly answer your question but here is a fact.

The images must either be stored in a host(Google Drive, Godaddy, etc) where I can access them using a URL or stored privately in a drive owned by the owner of the spreadsheet(Editor access still work).

Without this being in place, you would not be able to make use of the image(i.e. the image URL would never resolve to an actual image) in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a button that will let me to select and upload an image into a specific cell if I stored my images inside my Google Drive folder or Desktop folder? I am the owner of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes.

If the images are stored in a Google Drive that is owned by the same account that owns the spreadsheet then this is possible.

Comment: You can create a spreadsheet addon(Google Apps Script + HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT) with a custom form that allows you to upload image(s) to your drive and append the resulting URL to a cellImage(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/cell-image) operation.

There are multiple ways to approach this task, and this is just one of them.

Comment: For someone with little experience, are there any recommended guides to accomplish this?